# Get MVC partialView/View data in string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a requirement where I need HTML data from View to be saved in a string variable, something like this

`string data = GetData(Id)`

and GetData is a method which returns View like

`public ActionResult GetData(int Id)
        { 
            return PartialView("ViewName");
        }`

My requirement is to get whatever this View creates/return as an HTML to be assigned to `string` variable `data`

Is it actually possible?

Thanks for Help

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 public static string GetTemplateContentInstance(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, object model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(viewName))
            //Return name of view for current action
            viewName = controllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

        controllerContext.Controller.ViewData.Model = model;
        using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controllerContext, viewName);
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(controllerContext, viewResult.View, controllerContext.Controller.ViewData, controllerContext.Controller.TempData, stringWriter);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, stringWriter);

            return stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

Use as below

```
 string viewBody = GetTemplateContentInstance(this.ControllerContext, Url.Content("ViewName"), ModelName)
```

Comment: Amit: just to calrify, what above code suggest is i add my data in a ````Model```` and then pass that ````Model```` as parameter? Is it what ModelName is?

Comment: this is your modelname that render your view else pass as null

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private string GetHtmlFromUrl(string url)
{
    string html = "";
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    // get the response stream.
    //Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    // use a stream reader that understands UTF8
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
    html = reader.ReadToEnd();
    // close the reader
    reader.Close();
    response.Close();
    return html;//return content html
}
```

Usage:

```
string data = GetHtmlFromURL("/YourController/GetData/{ID}") 
//or GetHtmlFromURL("/YourController/GetData?ID={ID}") if your route isn't set to accept ID
```

Comment: Thanks Michael for quick response, I have copied your code but get this error ````The name 'GetHtmlFromURL' does not exist in the current context```` . I have copied over ````GetHtmlFromURL```` method in same class but cant see why should get this error. Any idea?

Comment: I'd need to see more of your code to tell you. Update your question with what you have currently.

Answer (score 0):

You try to create an instance of an HtmlHelper and use the RenderPartial extension methods within that helper

Note: you need to include a using to System.Web.Mvc.Html to access the RenderPartial

```
public static HtmlHelper GetHtmlHelper( this Controller controller )
        {
            var viewContext = new ViewContext( controller.ControllerContext, new FakeView(), controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, TextWriter.Null );
            new HtmlHelper( viewContext, new ViewPage() ).RenderPartial("/mypartial");
        }

        public class FakeView : IView
        {
            public void Render( ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer )
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }
```

Comment: is ````/mypartial```` method name or url? How can i call ````HtmlHelper```` method

Comment: would be the path to the partial view